# How to make two selected indexes match in pdf dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, pdf-form

I have a form I created in pdf that basically has a dropdown with the student's names that uses their Student ID's as the values.  Pretty straightforward.  I am able to populate another field (textbox) with the value of the selected item in the dropdown.  Works great.  I have searched in whatever ways I know how, but I am unable to find an answer to this question:

I have a second dropdown that I very simply want to populate with the same selected index as the first. In other words the selected indexes of both dropdowns will always match each other (I don't need a two way function, I just want the second dropdown to match the first.).  I don't know of a way to assign two values to each dropdown item or I would try that.  In theory, this problem seems like it should be really simple to solve, but I guess that's what makes me, me.
Here is the simple code I use to get the value from the dropdown and populate the textbox:

```
event.value = this.getField("Fieldname").value;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, I finally realized there actually IS a simple way to do this.  Let me try to explain.  The first dropdown has student names using their student ID's as the VALUES.  The ID text box pulls the values from the selected name to display the id number.  I needed the third dropdown field to display the address.  Here's how simple that was:

I called the value from the textbox (which was the student ID).  I set up the third dropbdown to have the address as the display and the Student ID as the VALUE of the address.  I then just set it up like the iroginal:

```
event.value = this.getField("Fieldname").value;
```

Voila! It now displays the address in the third field.

It seems like you can actually daisy chain this method repeatedly to autofill even more fields if you needed to.